# Dash bootstrap component Modal not working in production environment

Tags: python, openshift, plotly-dash, gunicorn

I have a dbc Modal component in my Python Dash webapp. While the Modal is open, I have a dash dcc interval running that triggers a callback that updates the text in the Modal.

All of this works fine locally on the standard werkzeug development server, but when I publish in an OpenShift environment the Modal never opens. I'm printing the text that should be shown in the Modal to the console as well and that seems to work fine.

I run my app with the following command:

`CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8050 html_pagina:server -k gevent --worker-connections 10 --workers 4`

I have tried running it on the development server, then the Modal does show up. It only doesn't show up on when I run with the gunicorn command.